# SVG Polyline with stroke-linejoin:round not showing a rounded corner

Tags: svg

I'm seeing a strange rendering issue in an SVG that I'm generating.  I've narrowed it down to a small reproducible case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline points="41,36 40,35 42,37" style="stroke:black; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-width:70"/>
</svg>
```

This renders as 
[image: http://cl.ly/3f023z1w281D1Y2K3d0Q] 
(at least when viewed in Safari, Mac Chrome, or Mac Firefox).  I would expect something that looks more like a very slightly deformed circle.

Am I missing something?  I'm very new to SVG, so hopefully there's something obvious I've overlooked.

Comment: I know this doesn't help you *at all*, but it works fine in my Firefox and Chrome on Linux. So it probably is a rendering bug in Cocoa or whatever lib those browsers use on Mac.

Comment: Interesting -- it actually looks fine in Inkscape on my computer.  So probably just an issue with Firefox and Webkit rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the rendering in Safari v5.0.4 on Windows is this:
[image: Half Circle]

The appearance on Chrome 11.0.696.25 beta (Windows) matches what is desired:
[image: Oblong Circle]

The problem stems from the fact that three points that you have chosen are all exactly along a line and make a 180 degree turn. You get similarly 'bad' results if you use `points="100,0 110,0 90,0"`. If you change the first point from `41,36` to `41.01,36` then you see correct results in Safari (and the WebKit nightly build current as of this posting):
[image: Full Circle]

This simply appears to be a ~bug in some rendering engines, specifically how they choose to draw `stroke-linejoin:round` when the line makes exactly a 180 degree turn. I have created [a test page](http://phrogz.net/SVG/test_linejoin_round.xhtml) showing this issue as part of [a bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57470) against WebKit.